# How to instantiate an object in Powershell which must derive from a .Net abstract class

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I want to use **Powershell** to insert entities into **Azure Table Storage** and therefore need to instantiate a class which derives from the .NET *abstract* class `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceEntity`

I am thinking to instantiate (in a Powershell 2.0 script) an object using eg **New-Object** and then adding members using Add-Member but cannot achieve the instantiation of a compatible TableServiceEntity derived class. (I can instantiate other arbitrary PSObjects, but they won't do it seems)

Alternatively if someone could show me how to instantiate and populate ***ANY*** object class which could then be passed into the `tableServiceContext.AddObject()` method

Comment: Can you be more specific and post us some code examples, including part where you reference assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to create your class in a cs file and then reference it to your script. 
Here's example:
Save this as a cs file:

```
using System.Collections;
    public  class MyList : System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
    {
        public static string Test(string input)
        {
            return string.Format("test input {0}", input);
        }
    }
```

And here's the code to run it:

```
cd c:\pst
Add-Type -Path "2.cs" #-ReferencedAssemblies $assembly
[MyList]::Test("aaa")
```

You might need to pass your assembly to ReferencedAssemblies . And you also might need to upload assemblies into your script

The way to create table is described here:
[Add or replace entity in Azure Table Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466764/add-or-replace-entity-in-azure-table-storage)

Comment: Good idea, but is there no Powershell only way to do it?

Comment: If you will find a C# code that is doing exactly what you want - it can be rewritten to PowerShell. Edit your main post and people will help you.

Comment: Thanks. This _has_ helped and proved to be the seed of the solution. What I did in the end was to use **Add-Type** with the **-TypeDefinition** parameter  to specify a short class definition which simply inherits from the abstract .NET base class (in this case **TableServiceEntity**) and now have a standalone Powershell script working

Comment: Yes, I accept it, bt dont have the points to vote it up. Many thanks for your quick response.